# How to join the military?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Is it possible to join the military in GTA 5? If so, how?

Comment: I think you bought the wrong game.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more about speculation and suggestion of features to a game rather than about the game itself

Comment: @JohnoBoy By that logic, every question about how to do something should be closed. Just because the answer to this question is "you can't" doesn't make it off-topic.

Comment: I'm not saying every question like this should be closed, I'm saying this one is past that and into the wishful thinking zone.

Comment: This is less of a question and more of a "I wish we could do this stuff", never mind entirely wrong game franchice for it...

Comment: I agree it falls under the "open-ended, hypothetical: “What if *x* happened?"" type of question. On the other hand, it could have been an entirely sincere inquiry into the possibilities of the game.

Answer (score 12):

I think you greatly misunderstand what kind of game GTA is. It is not a game where you "join" anything or anyone; it is a game where your player character lives his life by completing missions for (sometimes random) individuals.

The only GTA game I know of, in which you are actually part of the military, is [Vice City Stories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Theft_Auto:_Vice_City_Stories) in which you start as a corporal doing odd jobs for your corrupt superior, which eventually leads to your discharge from the army fairly early on.

Although you *can* play as a firefighter or policeman in most GTA games, you are *never* actually a real firefighter or policeman, only a random criminal who stole a firetruck or cop car and does their job for fun.

In GTA 5 you can...

- pilot [fighter](http://gta.wikia.com/P-996_Lazer) [aircrafts](http://gta.wikia.com/Besra) or [other military planes](http://gta.wikia.com/Titan), assuming you manage to steal one from [Fort Zancudo](http://gta.wikia.com/Fort_Zancudo).
- pretend to be a soldier or marine if you've got the right clothes and weapons. Soldiers will still try to kill you if you enter Fort Zancudo, since you're never actually a real soldier.
- pilot helicopters, even [military ones](http://gta.wikia.com/Cargobob). Again, this is assuming you manage to steal them first. The [Buzzard](http://gta.wikia.com/Buzzard) can be bought as well.
- skydive. Whenever you enter an aircraft, you'll automatically get a [parachute](http://gta.wikia.com/Parachute).
- pilot a [tank](http://gta.wikia.com/Rhino) or [other](http://gta.wikia.com/Barracks_Semi) military [vehicles](http://gta.wikia.com/Barracks_OL).

If you want to be a military police officer, general, or whatever military worker you fancy, you'll have to do with [make believe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_believe).

Answer (score 2):

You can, in a roleplay server on [FiveM](https://fivem.net/) (a multiplayer mod for GTA V).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/277739)

Comment: @Joachim Sounds like an answer to me. Q: How do I join the military in GTA V? A: You can, in a roleplay server like FiveM.

Comment: @galacticninja By telling the OP to install a mod and join a roleplaying server, the answer is essentially telling the OP to play a completely different game.

Comment: @duskwuff My reply to `@Joachim was *not* a comment about this answer's *quality*, but a comment on whether this post was an *answer* at all. Posts that do not answer a question are deleted. See https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers

Comment: @galacticninja Right, I know. Here's my concern: an answer which straight-out said "play Call of Duty instead" would clearly be NAA, and this answer is coming very close to that by telling the OP to heavily modify the game and roleplay online _instead of_ playing GTA V.

Comment: @duskwuff Answers recommending mods as *solutions* to questions are not uncommon (and not NAA) here: https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6830/4797  Playing a game with mods is still playing the same game. GTA V has a large number of mods and an active modding community so I'm not surprised that this is an answer. If this answer's quality seems poor to you, perhaps a downvote is more appropriate rather than a delete flag/vote.

Comment: @galacticninja In this case, though, the mod doesn't even solve the OP's problem. FiveM only adds online play; the features that the OP requested are only added through roleplay (e.g, pretending that the feature exists). That's the part that I object to -- roleplaying feels like a non-answer, in that it can theoretically "allow" the player to do anything, but only in a way that doesn't involve the expected gameplay. Anyways, I didn't flag the answer, I'm just objecting to it. :)

Comment: @duskwuff I've looked at some roleplay mods/servers for FiveM. It seems that the mods are not purely roleplaying, in that the modifications are not just cosmetics. The mods change game mechanics like how NPCs behave and react to you. New missions or activities with new mechanics can be added. These can not be done in the non-modded game.

Comment: @galacticninja Just to appease, I indeed felt it was blurry territory. It's like asking if you can place bear traps in Skyrim, and then being told to download Wyrmstooth: it's a huge deviation from the vanilla game, but running on (or within) the same framework. But I agree, my VTC was misplaced :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are playing on PC or a j-tagged XBOX or PlayStation on can install the Police Mod. It is free and requires Script Hook V. It is downloadable from https://www.gta5-mods.com/scripts/police-mod-1-0b. Remember as you need Script Hook V, you will not be able to go online for the duration in which you have these mods.

Comment: The linked page currently states: "page you were looking for doesn't exist." Anyone know if there's an updated link or of a similar mod?

Comment: [This mod](https://www.lcpdfr.com/lspdfr/index/), called LCPDFR, has similar functionality, but I'm not sure if I can just edit it in, because it obviously is a different mod with different requirements.

Answer (score -1):

Well you cant join lmao. BUT, you can go to into "director mode" Selet "actors" go down to "military" and selet a soldier, then go to Fort Zancudo. :)